# Close and Open QDialog from QDialog 2

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qdialog

So, I have two QDialogs in 2 different classes, in one Qdialog I have a QTableWidget with some data from a MYSQL db, I want to close and re-open it when I close the second Qdialog, so this is what I tried but doesn't work:

```
class firstDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
   *all my code*
class secondDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def firstdial(self):
        self.firstdial= firstDialog()
        self.firstdial.show()
    def closeandopen(self)
        self.accept()
        firstDialog.accept()
        self.firstdial()
```

Comment: So, you want to *hide* the first dialog, show the second, and when the second is closed, show again the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to hide the first dialog upon launching the second dialog, and then having the second dialog emit a closing signal during it's `closeEvent` that can be connected to a slot in the first dialog that makes it visible again once received.

I am extending the example used in one your previous question.  I included some inline notes to explain where the changes are and what they are doing.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def populate_table(table):
    for i in range(10):
        table.insertRow(table.rowCount())
        for j in range(2):
            item = QTableWidgetItem(type=0)
            item.setText(f"({i}, {j})")
            table.setItem(i,j,item)

class Dialog2(QDialog):

    tableInfoChanged = pyqtSignal([int, int, str])
    closing = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        populate_table(self.table)
        self.table.cellChanged.connect(self.emitChangedInfo)

    def emitChangedInfo(self, row, col):
        text = self.table.item(row, col).text()
        self.tableInfoChanged.emit(row, col, text)

    def closeEvent(self, event):  # override the close event
        self.closing.emit()       # emit closing signal
        super().closeEvent(event) # let normal close event continue


class Dialog1(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.button = QPushButton("Push to open dialog2")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        populate_table(self.table)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.openDialog2)

    def updateTable(self, row, col, text):
        self.table.item(row,col).setText(text)

    def openDialog2(self):
        self.dialog2 = Dialog2()
        self.dialog2.tableInfoChanged.connect(self.updateTable)
        # connect to the closing signal for second dialog
        self.dialog2.closing.connect(lambda: self.setVisible(True))  
        self.setVisible(False)  # Hide the first dialog
        self.dialog2.open()     # Launch second dialog


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Dialog1()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```